# .htaccess not working in subdirectory

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file should remove .php extensions in a url, force a slash and assign get values where required. Where a script/file/directory is not found, it redirects you to the root. For example it works perfectly if you type `http://127.0.0.1/about-us/` it takes you to `http://about-us.php` or if you type `http://127.0.0.1/file/delete-avatar/230` it rewrites to `http://127.0.0.1/file.php?a=delete-avatar&id=230`, or if you type `http://127.0.0.1/nu` (where nu is an existing directory) it takes you to `http://127.0.0.1/nu`. However when you put a script inside a directory and append a GET value the .htaccess fails to rewrite and redirects to the index. For example, if you type `http://127.0.0.1/nu/login/recover-password` does not rewrite to `http://127.0.0.1/nu/login?a=recover-password`. My .htaccess is here

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /     

   # remove php extensions (only for GET method)
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.php(?:\?|\s) [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
   RewriteRule ^ %1/? [L,R=301]

   # don't touch other existing files/folders
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^ - [L]

   # force trailing slash
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1/ [L,R=301] 

   # rewrite extensionless php files
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
   RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.php [L]

   #subscribe
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?a=$2 [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?a=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]

   # finally, if not found
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is there a `/nu/login.php` file?

Comment: Yes. The file exists.

Comment: @anubhava take a look at this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389702/htaccess-causes-infinite-loop-on-live-server-but-works-on-localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this new rule **just below** `#subscribe` line:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?a=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?a=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: your solution is failing in some instances. For example I am not able  to access `http://127.0.0.1/nu/users/edit/myusername` where it should go to `http://127.0.0.1/nu/users/edit.php?a=myusername`. Where `nu` is an existing directory and `users` is another directory inside `nu` and `edit.php` is a script inside `users` so I have my tree like so /document_root/nu/users/edit.php

Comment: Of course it won't handle that URL because this rule is for `http://127.0.0.1/nu/login/recover-password` and here you have **one more level** in your new URL.  See updated answer.