# .htaccess causes infinite loop on live server but works on localhost

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm a newbie .htaccess and regex. I have a script that works locally but when I upload it to a live server it causes an infinite loop. How can I fix this? On the site when you load `http://example.com` if you are unauthenticated it takes you to `http://example.com/auth/` for a login form, else it displays the contents of `http:///example.com/index.php`. It works fine locally but when I upload on a live server, it cannot find `auth.php` so it redirects to the index page and because the user is not authenticated it sends to `auth.php` thus the infinite loop. Please help. Thanks.

**This is my file**

```
Options -Indexes
Options -MultiViews    
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /     

   # remove php extensions (only for GET method)
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.php(?:\?|\s) [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
   RewriteRule ^ %1/? [L,R=301]

   # don't touch other existing files/folders
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^ - [L]

   # force trailing slash
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1/ [L,R=301] 

   # rewrite extensionless php files
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
   RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.php [L]

   #rewrite path to file eg http://example.com/auth/recover to http://example.com/auth.php?a=recover
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?a=$2 [QSA,L]

   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?a=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]

   # finally, if not found
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Down vote without a comment??? Really??? Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling and reading and trying and testing, I got the way to resolve godaddy's funny .htaccess probles. I solved it here.

https://serverfault.com/questions/720085/htaccess-causes-infinite-loop-on-live-server-but-works-on-localhost/

Answer (score 0):

You can reorder your rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /     

   # remove php extensions (only for GET method)
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.php(?:\?|\s) [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
   RewriteRule ^ %1/? [L,R=301]

   # don't touch other existing files/folders
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} \d
   RewriteRule ^ - [L]

   # force trailing slash
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
   RewriteRule ^(.+?[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301] 

   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?a=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]

   #rewrite path to file eg http://example.com/auth/recover to http://example.com/auth.php?a=recover
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?a=$2 [QSA,L]

   # rewrite extensionless php files
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
   RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1.php [L]

   # finally, if not found
   RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Still looping. The site is hosted on godaddy

Comment: GoDaddy sometime doesn't have htaccess enabled. Location of .htaccess can be another issue. Why `auth.php` is not being found?

Comment: .htaccess and auth.php are in the same folder which is the root folder from which I am serving my webpages, my htdocs. The site is a subdomain on a godaddy hosted account.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why `auth.php` is not being found. Try my updated rules after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Still doesn't work, I even tried to rename the script to login.php but still fails

Comment: You will need to debug this (may be using RewriteLog) since these rules are working fine on my Apache.

Comment: Thanks. Will post the solution here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88769/discussion-between-ukavi-and-anubhava).